# ------device_container_node-2------ error: install/canopen_tests/share/canopen_tests/config/cia402/cia402_device_1.bin: No such file or directory ]

Tags: launch, master-slave, ros2, canopen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFIhE.png)

[image]

Hello , just running the example **" ros2 launch canopen_tests cia402_setup.launch.py "**

I get this error. Has anyone else encountered this problem before ?

Any Help very appreciated .